# Angular subscribe / unsubscribe best practices

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm currently wondering about angular subscription and unsubscription. There is a lot of stuff on the subject, so I'm a bit lost in all of this.

When should I unsubscribe from subscription ? What happens if I don't, ever, unsubscribe from them ? I never encounter any errors from reliquat subscription.

Is there a way to auto unsubscribe from everything in a component/app, so that I don't have to declare 1 property by subscription ? This can be very annoying :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'subscriptionTest',
  template: `...`,
})
export class SubTestComponent {
  first;
  second;
  third;

  constructor(private remote: RemoteService){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.first = remote.getSomeData().subscribe(data => // do something);
    this.second = Observable.interval(500).subscribe(event => // do something);
    this.third = remote.getSomeOtherData().subscribe(data => // do something);

  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.first.unsubscribe();
    this.second.unsubscribe();
    this.third.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription this might be helpful. Also this is another gud article on how and when to unsubscribe. https://medium.com/@benlesh/rxjs-dont-unsubscribe-6753ed4fda87

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `takeUntil` operator is a simple way to "auto" unsubscribe from any subscription, example :

```
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.apollo.watchQuery({
        query: gql`
        query getAllPosts {
          allPosts {
            title
            description
            publishedAt
          }
        }
      `
      })
      .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      .subscribe(({data}) => {
        console.log(data);
      });
      remote.getSomeData().subscribe(data => // do something);
      Observable.interval(500).subscribe(event => // do something);
      remote.getSomeOtherData().subscribe(data => // do something);
  }

  onStartInterval() {
    Observable
      .interval(250)
      .takeUntil(this.destroy$)
      .subscribe(val => {
        console.log('Current value:', val);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.destroy$.next(true);
    // Now let's also unsubscribe from the subject itself:
    this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

You don't have to declare each subscription , only to add the `.takeUntil(this.destroy$)` operator on each of them

Source : https://alligator.io/angular/takeuntil-rxjs-unsubscribe/

An amazing post about subscriptions : [Angular/RxJs When should I unsubscribe from `Subscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription)

Comment: The best way is use Subscription class.
You can i.e.:
    Create a variable, like subs: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;

    And then...
    this.subs.add(this.route.data.subscribe(...

    or 

    this.subs.add(this.clientService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(...

And in your ngOnDestroy() make a unique call, like
    this.subs.unsubscribe();

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to repeat yourself, use a super class:

```
/**
*  Unsubscribe from any Observable using takeUntil and this.destroy$
*      someObservable.pipe( // lettable operators in rxjs ^5.5.0
*          ...
*          takeUntil(destroy$)
*      )
*      .subscribe(....
**/
export class Destroyer implements OnDestroy {
    destroy$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();

    ngOnDestroy() {
        // Unsubscribe from whatever used takeUntil(destroy$)
        this.destroy$.next(true);
        // Now let's also unsubscribe from the subject itself:
        this.destroy$.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Use that everywhere:

```
export class SomeComponent extends Destroyer{

   constructor(private remote: RemoteService){
       super();
   }

   ngOnInit() {
        remote.getSomeData()
              .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)) 
              //.takeUntil(this.destroy$) // before rxjs ^5.5.0
              .subscribe(data => {/* do something*/});

        Observable.interval(500)
              .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
              //.takeUntil(this.destroy$) // before rxjs ^5.5.0
              .subscribe(data => {/* do something*/});
      }
   }

   // optional. You don't need ngOnDestroy everywhere.
   ngOnDestroy(): void {

       // Let Destroyer trigger unsubscribe
       super.ngOnDestroy();

       // ...SomeComponent other cleanup.
   }


}
```

Comment: In Angular you don't have multiple inheritance, so this method can be difficult in some implementations of another needs of extends. Like an of many Angular's class for example.

Answer (score 4):

The best way is use Subscription class.

For that, you will create a variable in your component, like this...

```
private subs: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;
```

And then use like this...

```
this.subs.add(this.route.data.subscribe(...
```

or

```
this.subs.add(this.clientService.login(this.username, this.password).subscribe(...
```

And in your ngOnDestroy() make a unique call, like

```
this.subs.unsubscribe();
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `this.subs = Subscription.EMPTY; this.sub = foo$.subscribe(); this.subs.add(this.sub); console.log(this.sub.closed);`. Then `this.sub.closed` is always `true`, even when I don't call `this.subs.unsubscribe();`

Comment: This solution works replacing `subs: Subscription = Subscription.EMPTY;` with   `private subs = new Subscription();`

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party plugins like [ngx-auto-unsubscribe](https://github.com/NetanelBasal/ngx-auto-unsubscribe)

Comment: Oh thanks :) ! With this lib I still have to declare each subscription ? And I prefer not using a lib for something I can do with native code